# When are hints dropped in Cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra

There are 2 articles I read about Hinted Handoffs in Cassandra.

In [Article1](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesHintedHandoff.html) it states that the hints are discarded after `max_hint_window_in_ms` (3 hours by default), but according to [Article2](http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2018/03/21/hinted-handoff-gc-grace-demystified.html) the hints are discarded after `gc_grace_seconds`(default: 10 days). If we assume the defaults then when will the hints be discarded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in 2nd article, behavior is different depending on Cassandra version. The first link describes Cassandra 2.1, while 2nd article talks about 3.x versions.

What version of Cassandra do you use?

Comment: I am using cassandra version 2.1.16